# SSL_write returns SSL_ERR_SYSCALL while Err_get_error() returns 0

Tags: openssl

I edited my code and this is what it looks like now. The server is trying to write some bytes on the socket.

```
    int r;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = stderr;

    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    method = SSLv23_server_method();
    ERR_clear_error();

    if ( !ctx)
    {
        ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
        if (!ctx) {
            return 0;
        }

        SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1);



       if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "/home/cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {            
           ERR_print_errors_fp(fp);
        }

        if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "/home/key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 ) {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(fp);
        }
    }

    if (!ctx) {
        return;
     }

    SSL *ssl;
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, fd);

    ERR_clear_error();

     if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(fp);
     }

    int rce = 0;
    ERR_clear_error();

    char *buffer = (char *) malloc(iova.iov_len);
    memcpy(buffer, iova.iov_base, iova.iov_len);

    r = SSL_write(ssl, buffer, (int)iova.iov_len);

    // check how many bytes were written
    if ( r <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(fp);
        int err = errno;

        switch(SSL_get_error(ssl,r)){
            case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                continue;
            case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                syslog(LOG_INFO, "SSL read encountered an error %d. Peer disconnected.", SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN);
                break;
            case SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN:
                syslog(LOG_INFO, "SSL read encountered an error %d. Shutdown.", SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN);
                break;
            case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
                syslog(LOG_INFO, "SSL write encountered an error %d and %lu. SYSCALL", SSL_get_error(ssl,r), ERR_get_error());
                break;
            default:
                syslog(LOG_INFO, "SSL write encountered an error %d and %d. Quitting", SSL_get_error(ssl,r), err);
                break;
        }
```

Couple issues that I could not figure out -

1. SSL_accept() fails
2. SSL_write() then fails with SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN and err string = `error:00000002:lib(0):func(0):system lib`

What am I doing wrong here with `SSL_accept` and `SSL_write()` ?

---

I am trying to use Openssl to do `SSL_write()` and I get the following error during `SSL_write()`. The server is trying to write some bytes to the socket connection `fd` -

```
error:140D0114:SSL routines:SSL_write:uninitialized:ssl_lib.c:1039:
Error: error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib
```

Here is my code

```
    SSL *ssl;
    if ( !ctx )
      return 0; 
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

    //SSL_set_fd(ssl, fd);

    BIO *sbio = NULL;
    sbio = BIO_new_socket(fd, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    SSL_set_bio(ssl, sbio, sbio);
    ERR_clear_error();

    FILE *fp;
    fp = stderr;
    r = SSL_write(ssl, buffer, (len);

    if ( r <= 0 )
    {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(fp);

            switch(SSL_get_error(ssl,r)){
                case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                    syslog(LOG_INFO, "No real error. Continue.");
                    continue;
                case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                    syslog(LOG_INFO, "SSL read encountered an error %d. Peer disconnected.", SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN);
                    break;
                case SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN:
                    syslog(LOG_INFO, "SSL read encountered an error %d. Shutdown.", SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN);
                    break;
                case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
                    syslog(LOG_INFO, "SSL write encountered an error %d and %lu. SYSCALL", SSL_get_error(ssl,r), ERR_get_error());
                    break;
                default:
                    syslog(LOG_INFO, "SSL write encountered an error %d and %d. Quitting", SSL_get_error(ssl,r), err);
                    break;
    }
```

The SSL context (ctx) is valid to begin with.

I tried looking up an explanation of the error but did not find it. Nor did I find a similar issue that would resolve it. Can anyone help me understand what I can do to further debug this ? Or if they have a solution ?

Openssl version 1.0.2g

Comment: The server and the client can go thru the same code. There are no separate programs for the 2.

Comment: Perhaps SSL_accept() fails because it is non-blocking and does not wait for an incoming SSL_connect() from a client ? I will see what SSL_get_error() is returned by SSL_accept(). In the meantine, how can I make it blocking ?

Comment: So SSL_accept() returned error:00000002 which is SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ. My socket that I am trying to write to is non-blocking. So when I do a SSL_set_fd(ctx, fd) the SSL ctx is non-blocking as well.